# mavericks appstore download starts installing unintentionally

Tags: mac-appstore, data-transfer, vmware

I have been running Mavericks 10.9.4 on my system. with the release of 10.9.5 I preferred to re-download whole mavericks instead of just the combo update. This will be helpful if I clean install mavericks in that I would not have to install 10.9.4 and then run combo. Also it will take less storage in one pack. more manageable for me.

I started to re-download the mavericks from app store. It was a bit slower than last time. taking several hours. time to time I was checking progress in launch pad. After several hours when I checked back, system was in sleep mode. I logged and in AppStore, progress was 'Installing ... 9 minutes left' and stuck there for hours. several restarts I did but no avail.

**It is amazing why the install process started automatically without user interaction after the download completes?**

Secondly, I lost the purpose of downloading i-e the installer. My purpose was to save mavericks installer 10.9.5 for later use. But in app folder, the x icon is showing only a few KB. That is definitely unpleasing after approx 8 hrs of download.

**Where is the installer now which was downloaded ?**

Another attempt: I tried to download under a MAC-Mavericks(guest VMware on windows 7 Host). This machine's HDD is about 26GB. with plenty of space free. But after 3GB download, AppStore started giving error

**Error: 'We could not complete your purchase... you need 4.97GB of free space to download os x...'**

That is pinching. At this moment free space is 4.54GB. I am unable to delete anything from MAC components like iTunes etc to make little more space to complete the download. Also unable to expand this machines HDD from VMWARE. Perhaps there also space issue. The windows partition where this machine resides is 25GB with 10GB free. When I try to expand it says there is no free space on the file system for this  operation. Perhaps VMware expands in this way: first creates a duplicate of the main vmdk then do something to increase its space and delete the original vmdk. Or for other reasons it IS asking more space to increase the vmdk of mac vm.

**Please suggest something to get the purpose: obtain mavericks 10.9.5 fro App store for  later use. can something be done to preserve those above one complete and one half way (under vmware) download attempts **

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade as normal. Then if you need to do a clean install, use the recovery partition. Or is there something else you are after?

Comment: Thanks but I need to obtain full installer 10.9.5. I have no idea what I can do using recovery partition.

Answer (score 0):

1- To your first question (automatic Install)

Open App Store in your System Preferences and choose the correct settings there. (as shown)

[image: app store pref]

2- To your second question (how to get 10.9.5 Installer package)

Just click on the Mavericks download in App Store and you will get this:

[image: download mavericks]

Click Continue and you will have a Mavericks Installer package on you computer (after some time since it is a 5.5 Gig file). Do not run it!.

3- To your 3d question about space, you need 10 Gig of free space.

4- To your 4th question: Where is the Installer package?

Once the Installer runs it will delete it self when the process is completed.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I already started another download attempt in my running Mavericks. Step-1: I unchecked some marked checkboxes and now it is same as you mentioned. But I did this is after download started. I believe it will be applicable to my newly active download and will not start installer this time overnight.

Comment: step-2: yes did same as you mentioned.

Comment: step-3 I have 23GB free space now

Comment: step-4: can I trace installer during download or it just lies in /Applications folder? Somewhere mentioned to check here: /Users/yourAdminUserName/Library/Application Support/AppStore/ But I did not got it there. The 'X' icon in /Application folder is only 168 KB  while download is 1.65 GB so far. I am afraid not to loose installer this time. I hope it will show correct size after download completes and installer will not run by itself now after unchecking boxes in step-1.

Comment: SLEEP mode ?  I am gain leaving download overnight. should I disable sleep mode, so system doesn't sleep while I may and download continues.

Comment: It will be in your Applications folder named Install OS X Mavericks.app

Comment: If you have a problem with Internet disconnecting when in Sleep mode use terminal and type ping -i 600 Google.com That will tell your IP that you are active since you are sending a ping every 10 minutes. To stop it press ctrl- c

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it didn't go through. I left it on download while changed in App Store preferences not to install system file etc..

[image]

Download completed, installation proceeded on itself again and installer stuck at 9 min remaining showing in App Store purchases.

Like before, the X icon in Applications folder is 168KB only.

I found some stuff downloaded at a different location but I am not sure is it the installer can it be made the installer. because size shows similar to installer.

Here:

> **/applications/private/var/folders/8s/97n9msts6yb6tnly4djln2v00000gn/C/com.apple.appstore/675248567/aqk8899627438837780594.pkg**

[image]

In Applications folder, the X icon is 168KB only

[image]

Perhaps Apple have changed the download and install behavior for Maverick installer. Or may be it would behave same if downloading on recent versions of running Mavericks.

Please suggest something how can I get the Mavericks 10.9.5 installer now. Is there any way to do something with the above .pkg file to get the installer? can we avoid downloading third time??